# Вывод четных и нечетных цифр и сумма

Tags: javascript, строки

не могу решить вопрос. 
Суть, нужно написать функцию которя будет принимать число и значение 'odd' или 'even'
И так же посчитает всю сумму четных и нечетных цифр в зависимости от odd или even .
Вот так должно быть : пусть я ввел 123456 и odd - соответсвеноо в консоле у меня должно появиться 
--- 1 Нечетные - 1, 3 , 5.
--- 2 Сумма - 9.
И тоже самое с even.
Я написал код, который работает, но я там очень сильно намудрил и запутался вообще.

```js
function summ (number, evenOrOdd ) {
  let resultOdd = '';
  let resultEven = '';
  let resultCycleOdd = 0;
  let resultCycleEven = 0;

  if (evenOrOdd === 'odd') {
    evenOrOdd = number.toString();
  for (let i = 0; i < evenOrOdd.length; i++) {
    if (/[1357]/.test(evenOrOdd[i])) {
      resultOdd = resultOdd   + evenOrOdd[+i] ;  
  }
      number = +resultOdd;
      let sum = 0;
      while (number > 0) {
      sum += number % 10;
      number = Math.floor(number/10);
      resultCycleOdd = sum;
  }
    }
  console.log('Не парні' + ' ' + resultOdd); 
  console.log('Сумма'+ ' ' +resultCycleOdd);
}
  if (evenOrOdd === 'even') {
    evenOrOdd = number.toString();
  for (let i = 0; i < evenOrOdd.length; i++) {
    if (/[2468]/.test(evenOrOdd[i])) {
      resultEven = resultEven  + evenOrOdd[i] ;  
}
      number = +resultEven;
      let sum = 0;
      while (number > 0) {
      sum += number % 10;
      number = Math.floor(number/10);
      resultCycleEven = sum;
      }
  }
  console.log('Парні' + ' ' +resultEven);
  console.log('Сумма'+ ' ' +resultCycleEven);
  }
}
summ(123456789, 'even');
```

Comment: Если код работает, то в чем вопрос?

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать правильно. Тут же не вооруженным глазом видно, что он на костылях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function summ(num, evenOrOdd) {
  var resultLabel = [];
  var resultValue = 0;
  var numStr = num.toString();
  var numLength = numStr.length;
  var isEven = evenOrOdd === 'even';

  for(var i = 0; i < numLength; i++) {
    if ( (isEven && (i % 2 === 1)) || (!isEven && (i % 2 === 0))) {
      resultLabel.push(numStr[i]);
      resultValue += +numStr[i];
    }
  }
  
  console.log(isEven ? 'Парні: ' : 'Непарні: ', resultLabel.join(', '));
  console.log('Сума: ', resultValue );
}

summ(12345, 'even')
summ(12345, 'odd')
```

Comment: По-моему, в условии перепутаны четные и нечетные.

Answer (score 2):

Освобождаем код от ненужных переменных и приведений к строке

```
function summ(num, evenOrOdd) {
  var resultLabel = [];
  var resultValue = 0;
  var isEven = evenOrOdd === 'even';

  while (num > 0) {
    var lastDigit = num % 10
    if ( (isEven && ( lastDigit % 2 === 0)) || (!isEven && (lastDigit % 2 === 1))) {
       resultLabel.push(lastDigit);
       resultValue += lastDigit;
       num = (num - lastDigit) / 10;
    }
  }

  console.log(isEven ? 'Парні: ' : 'Непарні: ', resultLabel.join(', '));
  console.log('Сума: ', resultValue );
}

summ(12345, 'even')
summ(12345, 'odd')
```

За основу взял код из ответа Ofer.

Answer (score 2):

Немного функциональщины:

```js
sum = (nums, type) => (nums + '').split('').filter(e => type === 'even' && e % 2 === 0 || type === 'odd' && e % 2 === 1).reduce((a, c) => a + (+c), 0);
console.info(sum(123456, 'even'), // 2 + 4 + 6 = 12
sum(123456, 'odd'));              // 1 + 3 + 5 = 9
```

Comment: Коротко и ясно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getSum(string){
    let sum =0;
    for(s of string){
        sum= isNaN(parseInt(s)) ? sum+0:sum+parseInt(s);
    }    
    return sum;
}
function getNumbers(numbers,order){
    var num = String(numbers).split(""),
     res = order+' ';
    num.forEach(function(e,k){
     if (order=="odd"){
            if ((e % 2) === 1) {
             res += e;
            } 
        } 
        else if (order=="even"){
            if ((e % 2) === 0) {
             res += e;
            }
        }
    });
    res += ', sum = '+getSum(res);
    return res;
}

console.log(getNumbers(1234567,'odd'));
```